# Equivalent way for doing this using Swift arrays

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, swift, swift2

Suppose I have an array of `NSDictionaries` and each dictionary contains a key called "selected" that is a boolean stored as `NSNumber`.

If I want to know how many of these dictionaries have `selected = true`, I can do this:

```
let count = array!.valueForKeyPath("@sum.selected")?.integerValue
```

but this will work for an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries`. What about for a swift array of swift dictionaries like this

```
let dict1 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson1", "selected": false]
let dict2 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson2", "selected": true]
let dict3 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson3", "selected": true]

let array = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
```

OK, I can enumerate the array and count how many selected fields are true but I ask: is there a convenience method for doing that with Swift arrays like the @"sum.selected" on NSArrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `count` in swift

```
   let dict1 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson1", "selected": false]
    let dict2 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson2", "selected": true]
    let dict3 = ["name": "Toronto Pearson3", "selected": true]

    let array = [dict1, dict2, dict3]
    //Swift 1.2
    let result = count(filter(array){$0["selected"] == true})
    //Swift 2.0
    let result2 = array.filter{$0["selected"] == true}.count
    println(result)//2
```

Comment: swift 2 is giving me this error: **count is unavailable: access the count property on the collection**

Comment: I have not update to Swift 2.0 yet. I update the answer.From the error,you can use `filterdArray .count` to access the result

Comment: swift 2 - error on the filterdArray line: **filter is unavailable call the filter() method on the sequence**

Comment: you are missing some parenthesis there after array.filter...  `array.filter(` but now it is working. THANKS

Comment: Thanks for your comment,I update the answer to make it clear